# I need a solution for a gambling script

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a script for a gambling site.

What I need is that after 2 calls to the function `multiply`, it bets the maximum stake possible and after that calls the function `reset`, I mean in each two sequential loss it bets the full balance in my account reset for the minimum stake and continue playing, Because I realized that in odds of 1.1 on 'manual bet' in each 2 loss the next will be a won.

It is like: after 2 multiplyCalls bet the full balance (it is the "MAX" button in the image below) and reset the game to continue playing. Am I being clear enough?

I tried to create a function for this but did not work

The "Maximum stake" button element code is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="double_your_btc_max" style="color: inherit;">MAX</a>
```

[this is the printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KS0j.png)

The part of the script I want to modify is this, the multiplyCalls function is already created. I changed the `var multiply = (current * 2).toFixed(8);` to `var multiply = (current * 1).toFixed(8);` because my strategy does not have martingale.

```
function multiply(){
        if(multiplyCalls < 2){ // test multiply
            var current = $('#double_your_btc_stake').val();
            var multiply = (current * 2).toFixed(8);
            $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(multiply);
            multiplyCalls++; // increment
        }else{
            reset();
            console.log('=== RESETING ===');
        }
}
```

This is the full script:

```
var startValue = '0.00000001', // Don't lower the decimal point more than 4x of current balance
        stopPercentage = 0.001, // In %. I wouldn't recommend going past 0.08
        maxWait = 500, // In milliseconds
        stopped = false,
        stopBefore = 3; // In minutes
        multiplyCalls = 0; // <--- Added this global

var $loButton = $('#double_your_btc_bet_lo_button'),
                $hiButton = $('#double_your_btc_bet_hi_button');


function multiply(){
        if(multiplyCalls < 2){ // test multiply
            var current = $('#double_your_btc_stake').val();
            var multiply = (current * 1).toFixed(8);
            $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(multiply);
            multiplyCalls++; // increment
        }else{
            reset();
            console.log('=== RESETING ===');
        }
}

function getRandomWait(){
        var wait = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWait ) + 100;

        console.log('Waiting for ' + wait + 'ms before next bet.');

        return wait ;
}

function startGame(){
        console.log('Game started!');
        reset();
        $loButton.trigger('click');
}

function stopGame(){
        console.log('Game will stop soon! Let me finish.');
        stopped = true;
}

function reset(){
        $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(startValue);

}

// quick and dirty hack if you have very little bitcoins like 0.0000001
function deexponentize(number){
        return number * 1000000;
}

function iHaveEnoughMoni(){
        var balance = deexponentize(parseFloat($('#balance').text()));
        var current = deexponentize($('#double_your_btc_stake').val());

        return ((balance*2)/100) * (current*2) > stopPercentage/100;
}

function stopBeforeRedirect(){
        var minutes = parseInt($('title').text());

        if( minutes < stopBefore )
        {
                console.log('Approaching redirect! Stop the game so we don\'t get redirected while loosing.');
                stopGame();

                return true;
        }

        return false;
}

// Unbind old shit
$('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').unbind();
$('#double_your_btc_bet_win').unbind();

// Loser
$('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
        if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("lose")') )
        {
                console.log('You LOST! Multiplying your bet and betting again.');

                multiply();

                setTimeout(function(){
                        $loButton.trigger('click');
                }, getRandomWait());

                //$loButton.trigger('click');
        }
});

// Winner
$('#double_your_btc_bet_win').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
        if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("win")') )
        {
                if( stopBeforeRedirect() )
                {
                        return;
                }

                if( iHaveEnoughMoni() )
                {
                        console.log('You WON! But don\'t be greedy. Restarting!');

                        reset();

                        if( stopped )
                        {
                                stopped = false;
                                return false;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        console.log('You WON! Betting again');
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                        $loButton.trigger('click');
                }, getRandomWait());
                multiplyCalls = 0; // reset value
        }
});startGame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to max the bet after two losses.  Because multiply calls only occur after a loss, we can assume that the `if(multiplyCalls < 2)` bit takes care of that.  So in the following `else`, all you really need to do is hit max bet instead of call `reset()`.  Based on what I understand the code to be doing, this should be sufficient, correct?

```
function multiply(){
    if(multiplyCalls < 2){ // test multiply
        var current = $('#double_your_btc_stake').val();
        var multiply = (current * 1).toFixed(8);
        $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(multiply);
        multiplyCalls++; // increment
    }else{
        //reset(); /* instead of resetting here, let's max the bet. */
        $('#double_your_btc_max').trigger('click');
        console.log('=== RESETING ===');
    }
}
```